# Laravel Authentication doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with laravel 5.2, and I have a problem with customized authentication. It doesn't log the user on .
Here you can find my code for the function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $email = $request->get('email');
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

    if(! is_null($user))
    {
        if (Auth::login($user))
        {
            return redirect('/profile');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->register($request);
    }
}
```

In the place of Auth::login, I tried also the function attempt and check, but nothing was working ...
It logs the user, but it showed a blank page, without redirecting to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a blank page instead of being redirect to '/profile' because your second if condition is never true as

```
Auth::login($user)
```

never returns a null even if user is logged in 
so basically

```
if (Auth::login($user))
    {
        return redirect('/profile');
    }
```

this is if condition is never satisfied in your case.

You can try this

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $email = $request->get('email');
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

    if(! is_null($user))
    {
        Auth::login($user);
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect('/profile');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->register($request);
    }
}


Auth::check();
```

will return true if the user is logged in and will be redirected to '/profile'.